# using Mozilla FormData with jquery $.ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, fileapi

I am using html5 to allow allow drag and drop of files , and submit form data along with files  in a multipart/form-data request with the mozilla  FormData()  api ( there is a append() function for a FormData object and I append values and files with it ).   I use the jQuery.ajax() and set the data to the FormData object I created and set the processData flag to false, and contentType to "multipart/form-data" , with a beforeSend handler call jqXHR.setReqeustHeader("Conetent-Type", "multipart/form-data")  again . But in the firebug I can see that request header is still having Content-Type: text/html  .

It seems $.ajax() ignore my content type specification . Has anyone else successfually using jQuery.ajax() to work with FormData api of html5 ?

I know that I can make my own XMLHttpReqeust without help of jquery , and it works too . But I like a unified framework such as jquery.

Comment: You can set `contentType: 'multipart/form-data'` with jQuery, IIRC.

Comment: I did both the contentType: "multipart/form-data" , and the beforeSend event where I call jgXHR.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data")  .

Comment: I found another post that solves the problem . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392344/sending-multipart-formdata-with-jquery-ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set `contentType` to `false` instead of real content type. Also set `processData` to `false`. [Here is more details](https://coderwall.com/p/p-n7eq).